# Spring web page

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, spring-mvc

https://github.com/Alexandr056/WebChatStorage
Создал проект веб приложения, описал зависимости, создал контроллер, html страничку. При открытии из браузера страницы, получаю ошибку
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Mar 01 11:16:29 EAT 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

отладчиком посмотрел в метода контроллера попадает, но страницу не находит подскажите что не так?

Answer (score 0):

вопрос решен, нужна была зависимость

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

почему и как непонятно, но без нее отказывался найти main.html